# Enable connectionPool monitoring in websphere Liberty

Tags: prometheus, connection-pooling, websphere-liberty, jmx-exporter

I am trying to enable connection pool metrics for oracle database on websphere liberty server. As per this documentation https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-liberty/nd?topic=10-connectionpool-monitoring adding monitor-1.0 feature in featuremanager and adding this line *WebSphere:type=ConnectionPoolStats,name=<IDENTIFIER_OF_CONNECTION_MANAGER>*
in server.xml will start exposing connection pool metric but I am not sure what will be the value of <IDENTIFIER_OF_CONNECTION_MANAGER>.? Is it jdbc url.?

I am using jmx_exporter java agent and it is able to fetch other metrics including jvm metric but not fetching jdbc metrics.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [documentation page](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-liberty/core?topic=SSD28V_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.liberty.doc/com.ibm.websphere.appserver.api.connectionpool_1.1-javadoc/com/ibm/websphere/connectionpool/monitor/ConnectionPoolStatsMXBean.html) for Liberty,

> name is either the JNDI name, if defined, or id of the DataSource or ConnectionFactory. The id may be explicitly defined or generated by the server.

Typically, you will have a jndiName configured on your dataSource (or connectionFactory), for example,

```
<dataSource id="myDataSource" jndiName="jdbc/myDataSource">
  <jdbcDriver libraryRef="JDCBLib"/>
  <properties .../>
</dataSource>
```

In cases such as the above, us the value of the `jndiName` attribute, which in the above case is `jdbc/myDataSource`.

Here's an example without a `jndiName`, in which case the name, `dataSource[DefaultDataSource]/connectionManager`, is generated based on the dataSource `id` and lack of an explicitly defined connectionManager,

```
<dataSource id="DefaultDataSource">
  <jdbcDriver libraryRef="JDCBLib"/>
  <properties .../>
</dataSource>
```

Here's an example without a `jndiName`, in which case the name, `dataSource[DefaultDataSource]/connectionManager[default-0]`, is generated based on the dataSource `id` and nested connectionManager that is present,

```
<dataSource id="DefaultDataSource">
  <connectionManager maxPoolSize="10"/>
  <jdbcDriver libraryRef="JDCBLib"/>
  <properties .../>
</dataSource>
```

If you don't have a `jndiName` and your config doesn't look like one of the above, post your config and I can try to help you determine the identifier based on it.